# Sum of values in raster

Tags: python, raster, rioxarray

Upon importing a raster file, how can I get the sum of all values given in the raster file?

```
import rioxarray as rxr

raster= rxr.open_rasterio(
    'raster.tif',
    masked=True
    ).squeeze()
```

`raster.sum()` only yields cryptic output.

```
raster.sum()
Out[22]: 
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(1.0032373e+08, dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    spatial_ref  int32 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did works, but you have to extract the data from the DataArray.

This might be simpler:

```py
raster.values.sum()
```

Comment: Thank you! This has helped. Eventually I had to use `np.nansum(array.values)` though because of many `nan` values in my data set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is not python, but faster than using `rioxarray`.

```
gdal_translate -ot Float64 -strict -unscale raster.tif -of XYZ /vsistdout/|mawk -F" " 'BEGIN{CONVFMT = "%.20g";}$3>0{SUM=SUM+$3};END{printf("%.20g\n",SUM)}'
```